# How to use Eager loading(includes) with find_in_batches rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a large number of rows in the **users** table for which I need to apply eager loading to load user's comments.

`User.includes(:comments)`

Since the user set is too large it consumes a lot of memory while adding eager loading.

So after going through a couple of solutions I ended with below

```
User.select(:id).find_in_batches do |user|
  users = User.where(id: user_id).includes(:comments)
end
```

Is there a better way to perform eager loading with find_in_batches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [find_in_batches](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) like this:

```rb
User.where(id: user_ids).includes(:comments).find_in_batches do |users|
  users.each do |user|
    user.comment
  end
end
```

It will `eager_loading` `comments` by each batch automatically.